# DeprecationWarning: timers.unenroll() is deprecated. Please use clearTimeout instead

Tags: node.js

While following this youtube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPIjjFGYSJ4) to learn about node.js

I got this error

> $ nodemon index.js
>   (node:18129) [DEP0096] DeprecationWarning: timers.unenroll() is deprecated. Please use clearTimeout instead.

App server still able to run. However as I am trying to add router to add item as the video, it never go through successfully. However, I would call it half- successfully as I do see the data log in the terminal but never go back to database. as you can see, we can see xxx as name as  40 as price in the terminal after I queried

```
http://localhost:4000/products/add?name=xxx&price=40
```

in the browser as in the video around 10:52. (I got it working after hard-coding in the index.js file. Why can't I query it as the video did? ) I am assuming the timers.unenorll() causing this. but i Googled it, all i find is this [one](https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0096_timers_unenroll), and this [one](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v10.0.0/)(on https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v10.0.0/ page)

[image]

but don't know what to do with it. cant' find a solution.please help

```
$ node -v
v10.0.0
```

[image]

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

const SELECT_ALL_PRODUCT_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM products';

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'genius',
  password: 'genius',
  database: 'react_sql'
});

connection.connect(err => {
  if(err) {
    return err;
  }
});

console.log(connection);


app.get('/',(req, res) => {
  res.send('go to /products to see the genius gyms')
});

app.get('/products/add', (req, res) => {
  const {name, price} = req.query;
  //console.log(name, price); 
  const INSERT_PRODUCTS_QUERY = `INSERT INTO products(name, price) VALUES('${name}',${price})`;
  connection.query(INSERT_PRODUCTS_QUERY,(err, results) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.send(err)
    } else {
      return res.send('successfully added product')
    }

  });   
  });




app.get('/products', (req, res) => {
  connection.query(SELECT_ALL_PRODUCT_QUERY,(err,results) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.send(err)
    }
    else {
      return res.json({
        data: results
      })
    }
  });
});


app.listen(4000,() => {
    console.log(`Genius gyms listening on
    port 4000`)


});
```

Comment: Can you show us your index.js code?  I would assume that either your code or some module you are requiring is using the deprecated API.  From the little bit of research I did, it looks like this is probably caused by something you are requiring in.

Comment: sure thing. Please check.

Comment: @jfriend00 please share your thought.

Comment: The deprecation warning should not cause any issues you can just ignore it for now. Add this line `console.log(err, results);` to the callback function of `connection.query..`. What does it print?

Comment: I got the same warning after upgrading the node version to v10.0.0. But thats just a warning, the app still works fine.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
npm install mysql@2.16.0 --save
```

Just update the mysql library to latest version.

Comment: That worked perfectly. I would suggest to change the code to update to the latest possible version: `npm install mysql --save`. The npm command also updates an already installed package.

Comment: If you care only for the major but not the minor version, `npm install mysql@2` suffices. As of this writing, the version `2.17.1` is the most up-to-date 2 version, yet that may change in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The offender seems to be the mysql module at this spot in the code where you see a call to `Timers.unenroll(sequence)`:

https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/61b173cbc3e207c5497c6c45c98a4871c01701f3/lib/protocol/Protocol.js#L325

```
Protocol.prototype._dequeue = function(sequence) {
  Timers.unenroll(sequence);

  // No point in advancing the queue, we are dead
  if (this._fatalError) {
    return;
  }

  this._queue.shift();

  var sequence = this._queue[0];
  if (!sequence) {
    this.emit('drain');
    return;
  }

  this._parser.resetPacketNumber();

  this._startSequence(sequence);
};
```

From various comments on the node.js Github site, it sounds like the API has been deprecated, but won't be removed any time soon.  Hopefully, mysql will switch to a substitute at some point.  You could inquire on their Github site if you want to know more.  The specific issue has already been filed on the mysql site here: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2003 and the current response is that the mysql module does not yet support node.js 10.x.

That presumably means you could rollback your node version to 8.x if you wanted and the issue would probably be gone or just wait for a mysql version that does directly support nodejs 10.x.

Comment: if I rollback your node version to 8.x ,  are they any file I need to update, such as package file. anything that I need to be award of?

Comment: @StackExangeLearner - not that i know of

Comment: @StackExangeLearner - Did this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points for following the proper procedure.

Comment: I have mysql 2.18.1 and this is still an issue.