# Can't understand error in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

I am new to Node.js, and in my project, I run it in local (Node.js version is `9.10.1` on macOS) and in server (Node.js version is `10.6.0` on Ubuntu)

In local, everything runs well, but in server, when I run `node app.js`, I will get this following error

```
(node:17488) [DEP0095] DeprecationWarning: timers.enroll() is 
deprecated. Please use setTimeout instead.
(node:17488) [DEP0096] DeprecationWarning: timers.unenroll() is 
deprecated. Please use clearTimeout instead.
app runs on port 3000
```

How can I find where the issue is? Many thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50072849/deprecationwarning-timers-unenroll-is-deprecated-please-use-cleartimeout-ins

Answer (score 1):

Just use `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout` insteal of `timers.enroll` and `timers.unenroll`.

Check [DeprecationWarning: timers.unenroll() question](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/20261)

Answer (score 0):

Just update mysql version:

```
npm install mysql --save
```